# Google "Search Features": is it possible to get just these results from an API query?

Tags: api

Google has these great *mini-apps* they call "[Search Features](http://www.google.com/intl/en/help/features.html)", which they show for certain search keywords at the top of the page, in a special format.  Here's the weather example:

[image]

Now, I'm wondering if they have a way to access - either as embeddable html, or a structured-data response - this special content via an API somewhere.  I have no intention of even attempting to do something borderline illegal like scrape the content from returned page queries, and I'm just trying to see if they "serve up" this content somewhere in their labrynthe of APIs - free or freemium or pro or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the modules, I believe the "Search Features" are also known as "Knowledge Graph" results and sometimes "Google Now". Either way, no APIs exist but many alternative data sources do including [Freebase and others, according to this Quora discussion](https://www.quora.com/APIs/Is-there-a-Google-Knowledge-Graph-API-or-another-third-party-API-to-get-semantic-topic-suggestions-for-a-text-query).